# Explain the answer of tree induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics

(e) Write an induction definition for the set A of binary trees over {a,b} so that every node except the root in t is different from its parent.

ans: Basis: $<>, \text{tree}(<>,a,<>), \text{tree}(<>,b,<>) \in A$

Induction: if $t1=\text{tree}(L1,a,R1), t2=\text{tree}(L2,a,R2) \in A$ and $t1,t2 \in A$ then $\text{tree}(<>,b,t2), \text{tree}(t1,b,<>), \text{tree}(t1,b,t2) ∈A$

if $t1=\text{tree}(L1,b,R1), t2=\text{tree}(L2,b,R2)$ and $t1,t2 \in A$ then $\text{tree}(<>,a,t2), \text{tree}(t1,a,<>), \text{tree}(t1,a,t2) \in A$

how the Induction reveal that every node except the root in t is different from its parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a binary tree; every node has $2$ children. Since $\{a,b\}$ only has two elements, both of the children of any given node must be the same. That is to say, all the children (note: not all the descendants) of $a$ will be $b$, and vice versa.

With our basis we start by instantiating the most basic possible trees of this kind: a tree with no nodes, a tree with $a$ as the parent, and a tree with $b$ as the parent.

**Basis:**

$\langle \rangle \in A$

$\text{tree}(\langle\rangle, a, \langle\rangle) \in A$

$\text{tree}(\langle\rangle, b, \langle\rangle) \in A$

After this, it is obvious that to satisfy our criterion we must have the following be true of our set $A$:

Whenever there is a tree $T$ with parent $a$, there must also exist trees with $b$ as a parent and $T$ as a subtree (connected to either one, or both of the two branches), and when there is a tree $T_2$ with parent $b$, there must also exist trees with $a$ as a parent and $T_2$ connected in the same fashion.

This is equivalent to saying that any $a$ node in any tree can only have children that are $b$—and vice versa.

I think it is slightly better to rewrite your inductive step as follows.

**Inductive step:**

$t_1 = \text{tree}(L_1, a, R_1) \in A, t_2 = \text{tree}(L_2,a,R_2) \in A \implies \text{tree}(\langle\rangle,b,t_2) \in A, \text{tree}(t_1,b,\langle\rangle) \in A, \text{tree}(t_1,b,t_2) \in A$

$t_1 = \text{tree}(L_1, b, R_1) \in A, t_2 = \text{tree}(L_2,b,R_2) \in A \implies \text{tree}(\langle\rangle,a,t_2) \in A, \text{tree}(t_1,a,\langle\rangle) \in A, \text{tree}(t_1,a,t_2) \in A$

Comment: Omg i finally understood it!thx!

Comment: Glad to hear it.